# Por que não consigo usar module export para exportar variável

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, módulo-ecmascript

**Explicação:**

Bom galera no meu arquivo app.js tenho muitas linhas de códico ... Algumas funções ... Mais acho que isso não importa muito, então o que eu quero fazer é exportar uma variável que preciso usar em outro arquivo já tentei de tudo mais não vai, tentei até das maneiras mais simples.

**O que quero fazer:**

```
//app.js
token = 'Teste' //Variável que quero exportar
module.exports = {
 token:token
}
```

E no arquivo account.js

```
//account.js
x = require("./app.js");
console.log(x.token);
```

**Problema:** Galera se eu testar esse códico funciona, porém no meu projeto não tem só isso, eu tenho outras funções e importações de lib ... Porém não funciona ... Sempre dá **undefined**.

**Outra solução que encontrei:**

```
//app.js
token = 'Teste'
exports.token = token

//account.js
x = require("./app.js")
console.log(x.token)
```

Enfim, funcionou mas porque não funcionou do jeito que eu queria ? Não quero usar desta forma só porque funciona, até porque do jeito que queria fazer funciona em um arquivo que contenha só esse trecho, porém no meu arquivo não tem só isso, tem mais algumas funções ... E não sei se isso afeta a forma que quero fazer a exportação da variável.

O cenário em que quero aplicar a primeira forma que quero fazer:

```
async function verify(req,res,username,password){              
 db.serialize(async function (){
  const query = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE User = (?) AND Password = (?)'                                                     
  db.all(query,[username, password],async function(err,rows){    
   try{
    if(rows.length == 1){                                          
     console.time("time1")                                         
     await console.log(rows);                                      
     console.log("Correct user");             
     res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/index.handlebars");        
     module.exports = {
      rows:rows //Desta forma era pra funcionar 
     }                            
     console.timeEnd("time1")                                      
    }                                                        
    else{
    console.log("Incorrect user!")}}
   catch{
    console.error("\x1b[31m","Problema com a função de autenticação, erro: \n", err);
   }
  })
})}
```

Porém no meu arquivo account.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();                                        
const router = express.Router();                              
const rows = require("./app.js")                              
const io = require('socket.io')                               
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");             
const multer = require("multer");                             
const path = require("path");

app.engine("handlebars", handlebars({defaultLayout:false}));
app.set("view engine","handlebars");                         
app.get('/',(req,res) => {                                    
 res.render(__dirname + "/View/Account/account.handlebars")
 console.log(rows.rows);
 //Quando eu entrasse nessa rota eu queria que aparecesse o valor da variável da forma que eu queria exportar como havia explicado
});

module.exports = app
```

**Tipo de erro:** Undefined

Tem mais coisas no meu arquivo app.js mas só coloquei a função onde quero usar o módulo export.

Comment: Não tem nada de errado com nenhum dos seus códigos. Todos funcionam corretamente (exceto as aspas no final de `x.token`), mas creio que tenha sido um acidente durante a pergunta. Enfim, tente criar um [mcve] e trazer para cá. Não precisa incluir _todo_ o seu arquivo, somente tentar **reproduzir** o que não está dando certo (porque atualmente a pergunta está "ok").

Comment: Sim foi acidente vou editar, porém também vi que não tem problema quando você testa só desta forma porém meu códico app.js e account.js é bem maior do que mostrei e talvez isso interfira você acha que devo postar todo o códico dos arquivos aqui? Porque o códico original é grandinho

Comment: Eu editei como recomendou :)

Comment: @Guilherme você está dando o export dentro da função verify que nem está sendo chamada, talvez realizando a chamada dela no final do arquivo dê certo, mas você está fazendo no minimo algo peculiar, chamando o export dentro de uma função assincrona, talvez não fosse melhor exportar a função que retorna esse dado e então usar no account.js?

Comment: Ela está sim sendo chamada só mostrei onde tentei usar, mas o problema é que quando eu chamo a função da undefined não era pra acontecer isso.

Comment: E não posso exportar a função pq não vou usar a função só a variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, oque você deseja é manter algumas variáveis para um usuário em especifico entre as requisições, se este for o caso, você deve usar sessões.

de uma olhada no pacote npm express-session, talvez lhe satisfaça:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

exports é uma variável equivalente a global no escopo da função que você executa...não é recomendado usar variáveis globais para guarda variáveis que dependem de usuário para usuário, elas iram sobrescrever umas as outras

**ou**

se a questão não é está, mas simplesmente retorna a valor de ROW, de dentro da função verify
aconselho que refatore-o para usar Promise, resolvi refatorar e deixei alguns comentarios:

```
//removi o parametro req pós não é utilizados
function verify(res,username,password){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //não precisa de async, pós não há await dentro
        db.serialize(function (){
            const query = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE User = (?) AND Password = (?)'
            //não precisa de async, pós não há await dentro
            db.all(query,[username, password],function(err,rows){
                try{
                    if(rows.length == 1) {
                        console.time("time1");
                        //console.log não é uma função assincrona, não precisa de await
                        console.log(rows);
                        console.log("Correct user");
                        res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/index.handlebars"/*, objeto com variaveis para o handlerbars*/);
                        //não retorne a variavel pelo exports, exports é um globlal
                        //em um ambiente com varias requisições, passar as respostas de varias requisições por uma global não é nada recomendado, pós entre o tempo de definila e finalizar e retorna, ela já pode ter sido sobreescrita por outra requisição      
                        //isso ira retorna pelo await...;
                        resolve(rows);
                        console.timeEnd("time1")
                    } else {
                        console.log("Incorrect user!");
                        //adicionei um res.send, pós se a requisição nunca chamar res.send, o browser ira aguarda até gerar um erro "timeout" pós, nenhuma respostas foi enviada
                        res.send("Incorrect user!");
                    }
                } catch (e){
                    res.send("Problema com a função de autenticação");
                    console.error("\x1b[31m","Problema com a função de autenticação, erro: \n", err);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

*obs.: por não conhecer a API de DB utilizada, não adicionei os casos em que a query da errado (que também pode ser um motivo de row nunca ser definido)...

Comment: Então ...a variável pode ser sobrescrita por outra requisição, porém o que quero fazer é exportar a variável rows para meu arquivo account.js que vai percorrer o array e pegar o id do usuário, pra buscar uma foto que tem esse nome (que vai ser o id do usuário) e carregar essa foto na página account, porém pra isso preciso exportar a variável assim que fazer login só que preciso resolver isso na questão da variável ser sobrescrita, poderia me dar um guia ? Porque já tô com esse problema a um tempo

Comment: @Guilherme, você vai passar por parâmetros de funções/retorno se puder fazer isso em única requisição (que é o recomendado)..., e se você vai buscar por usuário em especifico, também é recomendado fazer isso na query, fazer isso no node js, vai aumentar o consumo de RAM e Rede bastante, desnecessariamente

Comment: @Guilherme a função verify como está na resposta retorna o rows; obs: o "res.send" só pode ser chamado uma vez, recomendo que você o-faça na apenas na narrow function que está no get, para evitar varios "res.send" espalhados por varios arquivos...que podem deixar o código mais difícil encontrar bugs; ah, pra pegar o retorno da função verify no get, você usar then().catch, ou mudar a declaração da narrow function, de "(req,res) => {" para "async (req,res) => {", e usar await verify(...

Comment: @Guilherme quanto a foto de perfil do usuario, se não precisar ser privada, você pode simplesmente salva-la em uma pasta publica de conteúdo estático, e usar algum propriedade unica como id do usuario como nome...; ah e se você está fazendo um sistema com logins; você vai precisar de sessões; olhe o link do express-session; e pesquise sobre logins e sessões no node-js, é bem comun tutoriais sobre sessões/logins pela internet, para qualquer plataforma

Comment: Sim, eu salvo o id do usuário como nome da foto, porém preciso carregar determinada foto para determinados usuários, porém quando eu faço login e vou pra Index, e a foto que deve ser carregada deve ser carregada na página account, porém como vou saber qual foto deve ser carregada a determinado usuário? Por mais que eu tenha salvado o id como nome da foto eu preciso do id do usuário que está acessando a rota para buscar a foto dele, e como conseguir o id do usuário se não for exportando? Porque minha página account é acessada na rota account.

Comment: Pensei na seguinte solução para meu problema, o usuário logar, eu salvar esse id no cookie e quando acessar a rota account, crio uma função para ler o valor do cookie capturando o id, e sabendo o id então buscar a foto e carregar, porém está solução não é tão elegante já que vi um post com uma maneira diferente de fazer porém lá é só passo a passo na teoria não tem prática e era usando banco de dados então não sei aplicar e se é possível de outro jeito a não ser este.

Comment: @Guilherme, você precisa de sessões, sessões são como cookies do lado do servidor! leia sobre sessões/logins...como recomendei, sessões é um "assunto" trivial para logins em servidores

Comment: como seu ultimo comentario sugeriu, você vai salva no "cookie", mas no "cookie do servidor", na sessão... é assim que se faz normalmente, boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

O contexto está um tanto confuso, mas acredito que o erro está na função assincrona.

A função `verify` que você criou é uma função assincrona, mas a palavra reservada `await` está no inicio do `console.log(...)`.
Assim, quando você exporta as variaveis, elas podem não ter tido tempo de ser geradas.

o `await` deve vir antes de uma `Promise`, como por exemplo antes de `db.all(....)` que fará uma consulta no banco de dados.

Comment: console.log não é assíncrono,

Answer (score -1):

se seu Node JS não suporta ES6 (versão anterior a 10), o erro é este:

```
module.exports = {
 token:token
}
//que pode ser
module.exports = {
 token
}
//ou
module.exports = {
 'token':token
}
```

ao fazer token:token, vocé ele cria um objeto com uma váriavel que tem tanto o nome quanto o valor igual a 'Teste', se você não deseja colocar um novo nome a variável, coloque apenas ela, se deseja dar um novo nome dentro do objeto, para evitar que o valor de outra variável seja usada como chave, use uma string, para evitar que o valor de outra variável seja utilizado como nome dentro do objeto

```
'novoNome':token,
```

isto é um dos recursos que antes do ES6 tornava Java script fácil de escrever e difícil de quebrar..., que as vezes pode lhe deixar confuso.

OBS.: se o nome da variável dentro do objeto, não fosse uma variável definida funcionaria...

Comment: Na verdade isso não está errado, essa forma mais simplista foi introduzida no ES6 e é chamada de "Object Property Value Shorthand", caso queira saber mais pode ver aqui: https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/

Comment: @VictorNogueira, mas até o node js 10, o ES6 não existe ou é experimental, e até final do ano passado, o node js 8 ainda era usado em produção, pelo google por exemplo (firebase), que tirou o suporte do node js 8 e adicionou o suporte ao 12, versões mais recentes do node JS ficam fora...